# codeigniter is it possible for the table to automatically update the records in my sql based on the current date?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, sql-update

codeigniter is it possible for the table to automatically update the records in my sql based on the current date? im trying to make it so that it will update my table record from pending to cancelled depending on if it passes a certain amount of days. should i just put in at the start? like in the front page. that as soon as someone opens the site it will get current date there and update?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I would have a think about what you are trying to achieve here. If this data is only used by your site, why does it need to be updated in advance of being looked at by a user? Can't you just include the necessary SQL in the code that's executed when the site is accessed? If you code it carefully you should be able to avoid performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Daily processing of data is best done as a cron task on the server.

```
0 12 * * * php /path_to_codeigniter/index.php customer pend_to_cancel
```

Where your controller may look like

```
class Customer extends MY_Controller {

    public function pend_to_cancel()
    {
        if($this->input->is_cli_request()) { 
            $this->where('renew_date >', date('Y-m-d'));
            $query = $this->get('customers');
            foreach ($query->result() as $customer_row) {
                // Check if customer should be set to suspend
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```